# Can view the history of a file remotely but not locally

Tags: git, gitlab

I migrated a project from svn to git. I can view any file's or directory's history using gitlab but when I try to view the history of any specific file locally (i.e. git log README.txt) it shows only the logs that I've made until this morning. (I suppose that I merged something by mistake at that time.) My question is, how can I view the history of the files on local repository as I can see them remotely? Since all the history exist remotely, there should be a problem on the local repository I think. I'm a Git newbie by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log --follow README.txt
```

is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since git is designed at its core as a distributed SCM, you'll need to ensure you've "fetched" all remote changes into your local repository before you will see the commits that you're seeing on the remote side.

Depending on how your repository is configured (the name of the remote, the name of the branch, whether your local branch is "tracking" a remote branch), you *might* be able to do something as simple as the following: `git pull`. This will fetch and merge commits for the configured [remote tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches), assuming one is configured (you can see what local branches are tracking remote branches via `git branch -vv`).

If your local branch is *not* tracking a remote branch, you'll need to use  a more specific version of `git pull` to merge the remote commits into your current (local) branch. If your remote branch is `master` and the remote's name is the default `origin`, this would just be `git pull origin master`.

If you'd like to simply see the *log* of commits without modifying your local branch at all, you should use `git fetch`. Again, if your remote's name is the default `origin` and the remote branch name is `master`, you can do this via `git fetch origin` (to retrieve commits) and then `git log origin/master` (to view the commits).

Comment: git log origin/master shows all the logs of the root folder from the beginning but if I type git log folder1/README.txt, I still can not view the history of README.txt even if I can see it remotely.

Comment: What about `git log origin/master folder1/README.txt`?

Comment: Same, just two logs until this morning... On the other hand, on gitlab, I can totally view the history from the beginning from 2009.

Comment: Until this log: Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.hostname.fr/teamname/projectname which I've done by mistake.